# build apk with jenkins? error: archive artifacts

Tags: jenkins, github, build, apk

I am tring to build an apk from my project that on github. Jenkins is connected with github...

Jenkins takes the project on my jenkins page, build it successfully but when it tries to archive artifacts it generates this error:

```
There are no matches for "** / *. Apk": "**" exists but "** / *. Apk" no
ERROR: Step ‘Archive artifacts’ failed: No artifact matching the pattern for "** / *. Apk" files was found. Is this a configuration error?
Finished: FAILURE.
```

I have tried all similar questions, but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: ${WORKSPACE}/path/to/aps/*.apk
```

Comment: where should i put this?

Comment: when you built apk. It could be same stage, next stage or even `post` section

Comment: sorry, I'm a beginner on jenkins, maybe it will be a silly question, but does jenkins process an apk file from scratch? it takes  the files from github? or at the moment of buil must an apk already exist and at the moment of the jenkins build simply check it or rework it? because I tried to make a build where there was already a .apk file and obviously it didn't give me errors, and it gave me back the apk in the result of the build ... but if I delete this apk from my repository on github then I rebuild the build then gives me this problem that it can't find ** / *. apk for archive artifacts

Comment: Of course you have to build your apk from your code first. i don't know which system you use, lets assume, you're using  `gradle buildRelease`. output will be your apk file, which could be archived by command `archiveArtifacts` with path specified.
You could specify apk path in you configuration (gradle etc) or build it on local machine, find that path and use it in Jnekins